# Does MemberwiseClone in C# do the same as = in Javascript when copying objects

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

Really sorry once again for asking such a noobie question, but I'm having real trouble getting my head around the answers I have found online and I just need to know for sure...

I am converting some Javascript to C# and one of the things in the JS is the line

```
this.shared.cascade.stage_classifier[i].orig_feature = this.shared.cascade.stage_classifier[i].feature;
```

Now feature is actually an array of features each of which contains numerous arrays of ints...

However when I use the same line in C# (having made the necessary classes inc class for a feature that contains the various arrays of ints) none of the said ints seem to have any values...

So basically I am just after the equivalent thing I need to use in C# to copy 'feature' to 'orig_feature' and have it do the same things (i.e. when values change in 'feature' in the JS I pretty sure they also change in 'orig_feature' too, though I am not sure about the vice-versa)

UNEDIT: It turned out something else was going wrong in my code so I removed the examples I placed here, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator does the same thing in both languages, it will copy the array reference from the `feature` property to the `orig_feature` property.

There will only be one array, with two references to it. When you use one reference to change the array you will see the changes when you access it using the other reference.

There is no "original" reference, so it works the same both ways.